# ChromeDriver DevTools fails to load the first launch

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Everytime I launch a new chromedriver, the launch takes about 4 seconds. After investigation it seems that it is initially failing to link to the devTools. Does anyone know why? I am running Chromedriver v80 and no i am not using selenium.

The log below is the verbose log. We start a session, then kill the session. As you can see by the warning it is unable to connect. I posted a bug on chromedrivers site but they said that it is because of the DevTools.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3301&can=1&q=slow&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

```
[1578872524.156][INFO]: Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614})
    [1578872524.157][INFO]: Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
    [1578872524.202][INFO]: [d98db911d9e19d2d0f6a8f4ec1622117] COMMAND InitSession {
       "capabilities": {
          "firstMatch": [ {
             "browserName": "chrome",
             "platformName": "windows"
          } ]
       }
    }
    [1578872524.205][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
       "alternate_error_pages": {
          "enabled": false
       },
       "autofill": {
          "enabled": false
       },
       "browser": {
          "check_default_browser": false
       },
       "distribution": {
          "import_bookmarks": false,
          "import_history": false,
          "import_search_engine": false,
          "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
          "skip_first_run_ui": true
       },
       "dns_prefetching": {
          "enabled": false
       },
       "profile": {
          "content_settings": {
             "pattern_pairs": {
                "https://*,*": {
                   "media-stream": {
                      "audio": "Default",
                      "video": "Default"
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          "default_content_setting_values": {
             "geolocation": 1
          },
          "default_content_settings": {
             "geolocation": 1,
             "mouselock": 1,
             "notifications": 1,
             "popups": 1,
             "ppapi-broker": 1
          },
          "password_manager_enabled": false
       },
       "safebrowsing": {
          "enabled": false
       },
       "search": {
          "suggest_enabled": false
       },
       "translate": {
          "enabled": false
       }
    }
    [1578872524.206][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
       "background_mode": {
          "enabled": false
       },
       "ssl": {
          "rev_checking": {
             "enabled": false
          }
       }
    }
    [1578872524.210][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --load-extension="C:\Users\mills\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir17204_501538308\internal" --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\mills\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir17204_1103078862" data:,
    [1578872524.696][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
    [1578872526.692][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
    [1578872526.694][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
    [1578872528.723][INFO]: [d98db911d9e19d2d0f6a8f4ec1622117] RESPONSE InitSession {
       "capabilities": {
          "acceptInsecureCerts": false,
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "browserVersion": "79.0.3945.117",
          "chrome": {
             "chromedriverVersion": "79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614})",
             "userDataDir": "C:\\Users\\mills\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir17204_1103078862"
          },
          "goog:chromeOptions": {
             "debuggerAddress": "localhost:49988"
          },
          "networkConnectionEnabled": false,
          "pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
          "platformName": "windows",
          "proxy": {

          },
          "setWindowRect": true,
          "strictFileInteractability": false,
          "timeouts": {
             "implicit": 0,
             "pageLoad": 300000,
             "script": 30000
          },
          "unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify"
       },
       "sessionId": "d98db911d9e19d2d0f6a8f4ec1622117"
    }
    [1578872528.739][INFO]: [d98db911d9e19d2d0f6a8f4ec1622117] COMMAND Quit {

    }
    [1578872528.784][INFO]: [d98db911d9e19d2d0f6a8f4ec1622117] RESPONSE Quit
```

Comment: Why tagging [tag:selenium-webdriver] when you are _...no i am not using selenium*..._? Am I missing something?

Comment: because selenium users are directly linked. selenium is just the framework on top of the w3c webdriver. i built my own framework which replaces the webdriver. also there is no tag for chromedriver or webdriver without selenium